# Log collection from Android devices

Tags: android, logging, monitoring, fluentd, fluent-bit

I've been reading recently about Fluentd and Fluent-bit as tools for log unifying and collection.
The documentation says it supports a few Linux distributions but I couldn't find any reference to Android - either that it is supported or not supported.

Any idea if Fluent-bit can be compiled to run on Android?
Alternatively, are there other tools such as Fluent-bit for Android?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, but honestly, I haven't been looking very hard as my interests have shifted dramatically a short time after I asked this question...